# Proble with chrome driver OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'chromedriver' 32bit Ubutu

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to install the updated chromedriver.Till yesterday working with old but give me an error message.I download lates driver from google amd 64bit.I am using Ubuntu 18.4 32bit.My chrome browser is  vesion 87 I unzip move and chmod +x chromedriver file in usr/bin/ And now I get an error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "instaabot.py", line 18, in 
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
> File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
> self.service.start()
> File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
> stdin=PIPE)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'chromedriver'

I read maybe I have more then one chromedriver so I don`t know witch to delite this is the list of chromedriver in my system:

```
/home/pc/.cache/pip/wheels/35/91/f2/52f5dd4aa6be444aba5b4de86a8bc6db24a975f616b1a14a5e

/instapy_chromedriver-2.44-py2-none-any.whl
/home/pc/.cache/pip/wheels/77/e7/8a/d92d1054fa5679b3ae2950df04f18569056bb081bc0dfc6cf7/instapy_chromedriver-2.46-py2-none-any.whl
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver/__init__.py
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver/__init__.pyc
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver/chromedriver_linux64
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver/chromedriver_mac64
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver/chromedriver_win32.exe
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info/INSTALLER
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info/METADATA
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info/RECORD
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info/WHEEL
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info/metadata.json
/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.44.dist-info/top_level.txt
/home/pc/Downloads/.chromedriver.swp
/home/pc/Downloads/chromedriver
/home/pc/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (1).zip
/home/pc/Downloads/chromedriver_win32.zip
/home/pc/instagramBot/instaDM/instagram-auto-dm/instagram-auto-dm/chromedriver.exe
/home/pc/instagramBot/instaDM/italyorder/.chromedriver.exe.swp
/home/pc/instagramBot/instaDM/italyorder/chromedriver.exe
/home/pc/instagramBot/instaautopost/auto-Instagram-posting-bot/chromedriver.exe
/opt/popcorntime/chromedriver
/usr/bin/.chromedriver.swo
/usr/bin/.chromedriver.swp
/usr/bin/chromedriver
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver_unittests.runtime_deps
/usr/share/doc/chromium-chromedriver
/usr/share/doc/chromium-chromedriver/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/chromium-chromedriver/copyright
/var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-chromedriver_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/chromium-chromedriver.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/chromium-chromedriver.md5sums
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall chromium-chromedriver
```